# Rails - Error pages controller and redirecting the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Building a small app and I'd like to intercept error pages.

Is it possible to define a controller where all of Rails's failed page requests end up so I can add my custom behavior there?

Comment: You can make use of rescue from specific errors like `not found`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: @Glorfindel not doing that but I'm trying to delete and it doesn't seemt o work. Edited some more to make the question more specific. Going to leave it alone maybe someone answers.

Comment: @unmircea You can’t delete your own question when it:

    has an upvoted answer, or
    has an accepted answer, or
    has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)

Comment: @Glorfindel Ok, got it!

Answer (score 0):

Place this at the bottom of your app config/routes.rb

```
match '*path', to: redirect('/'), via: :all
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think rescuing the error from the controller won't work because the request hasn't hit any controller yet for you to do a `rescue_from`. (Just tried this on 4.2.x)

You will need to add a catch-all kind of route into your `config/routes.rb`, right at the end of the all the others. This basically routes all the traffic that is not recognized to the `errors#show` action.

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  # ...
  get '*path', to: 'errors#show', via: :all
end
```

Then create the `ErrorsController` and the method for you to parse the URL.

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # parse the URL and redirect or simply render the page
  end
end
```

Do note that the above will not help with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` errors; because they fall into a route pattern for a specific controller. For that, you can add `rescue_from` in the `ApplicationController` as such:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :foo

  def foo
    # redirect or do something
  end
end
```